# SwiftUI + Problems with focus on TVOS after update to 16.4

Tags: swiftui, focus, tvos

All views in my SwiftUI TVOS application stopped working correctly after TVOS update to 16.4. Gestures recognition and buttons from Siri remote work, but elements in my views lose or do not set in focus (can't eve press or select any button). What ways can be to solve this issue ?

My main view contains several ones. I tried to remove all superfluous views except one, but no result. Also tried to debug elements focus manually with printing .onFocusChange in console, but also with no result. Tried to set elements in focus when ".onAppear" with no result What ways can be to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@FocusState`, that worked for me.

For example:

```swift
@FocusState var buttonFocus: Bool

var body: some View {
  Button("Button") {
    print("on tap")
  }
  .focused($buttonFocus)
  .onAppear {
    buttonFocus = true
  }
}
```